# How to process ">>" horizontally in bash

Tags: linux, bash, cat, dig

When I try the command

```
 dig +short ns kinoafisha.info >> text.csv
```

it gives the result

```
ns2.kinoafisha.info.
ns1.kinoafisha.info.
```

Is it possible to get results like

```
ns2.kinoafisha.info. , ns1.kinoafisha.info.
```

I got no clue... Please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with `awk`

`dig +short ns kinoafisha.info | awk -v RS='' '{gsub("\n", ", "); print}' >> text.csv`

Comment: Cleaner, no trailing comma.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
dig +short ns kinoafisha.info | tr '\n' , >> text.csv
```

If you need spaces around the `,`, you can add these as follows:

```
dig +short ns kinoafisha.info | tr '\n' , | sed 's/,/ , /g' >> text.csv
```